# Is there anyway to highlight and entire column in google sheets based on the value in the top column value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Is there anyway to highlight and entire column in google sheets based on the value in the top column value?

Currently I have my dates in row 2 that I have highlighted using conditional formatting, but I would like the whole column to be highlighted on the current date.

I am not sure about using a script or macro to change all the column backgrounds.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? Change cell background color or selecting the whole column?

Comment: Change the cell background of every row below the selected column which is "Today's" date

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear what you are looking for. Also add a brief description of your search/research efforts in order to make this a good question. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Formula:

```
=B2=Today()
```

Apply to:

```
B2:B
```

Comment: That works for what the formula says to do, but how do I apply it the entire column with still keeping text in the cells?

Comment: @Jeremy it'll work for the entire column, even if the formula only says B2